# Nexus OSS 3 Rest API

Tags: rest, jenkins, groovy, nexus

Any idea where we can find the Nexus 3 REST API documentation?  Or can we configure Nexus using Groovy script like we do in Jenkins?

In Jenkins we can use Jenkins cli jar to configure Jenkins. 
In older version of Nexus there is REST API documentation to manage Nexus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the documentation linked above, you can query https://your_nexus_url/service/rest/swagger.json, which at least documents the available parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It's [extraordinarily incomplete](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api), but there are some ["examples"](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x).

It seems that the client is relatively useful, per the examples.

Comment: The examples url has changed: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x